# Is it possible to automatically empty the firefox search bar?

Tags: firefox, search

I often select something I want to google with the mouse (no [ctrl-c], I'm on X11/Linux), so I can paste it into the search engine box in firefox. However, there's usually already something in there from a previous search, so I can't just paste it. This sits in my way all the time, so here's my question:

Is there a way to clear the search form as soon as I hit [enter]? So it'll be empty for the next time I search for something?

On Linux, I find that the [ctrl-c] ... [ctrl-v] should not be neccessary in that case, as it forces me to move the hand back to the keyboard (i'm left-handed).

This would also be helpful in cases I did google something that I don't want others to see. It's easy to forget that your last search is still up there, despite you closed the tab already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The addon [Searchload options](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/searchload-options/) does this.

Comment: Sadly, this add-on was removed by its author in 2015.

Answer (score 3):

Due to removal of support for old-style (XUL) Add-Ons since FF-57+ "Quantum" all above mentioned plugins are no longer compatible with current versions of FF.

Unfortunately the request has been declined (in [Bugzilla 1418024](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1418024)) to add the required functionality for implementation of such a feature thru the new "web extension" API of FF (cf. explanations at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295344/how-to-access-the-search-bar-in-a-firefox-57-quantum-web-extension)).

However, there is on going discussion whether the requested feature should be added as a configurable option of FF in [Bugzilla 253331](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=253331).

Answer (score 2):

Update: As @mirabilos mentioned in the comments, this addon no longer exists.

[Clear Search 2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/clear-search-2/) addon does exactly what you want. Its description:

> Clears the search bar after you perform a search, getting the old
> query out of the way. Useful for quickly pasting text into it, or for
> keeping your most recent query hidden.

Comment: This also no longer exists ☹ I recall using it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above there is a bug on this in the firefox site that is open 20 years now, I don’t think it will be changed anytime soon.

So for now you can add this clearing of the searchbox yourself in your own firefox

The downside is that every update that firefox does it will remove your fix and you will have to re-do it.

**Here is how you can change your own local firerfox to clear search terms after you search for them:**

Close all firefox instances

Download 7zip and install it (for editing files in compressed archives)

***Editing omni.js***

Browse to this folder:

> C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser

Right mouse drag omni.ja to some empty temp folder and choose 7zip->extract here

Then browse to this inner folder:

> \browser\content\browser\search\

rightclick searchbar.js and choose edit

search for this line (for me it was just around line 436):

> openTrustedLinkIn(submission.uri.spec, aWhere, params);

under it, add the following new line:

> textBox.value = "";

save it.

Select all the root folder content + right click , 7zip->add to archive

Change the archive format to “zip” and change the file name to omni.ja + click ok.

Replace the original omni.ja with the new one you created (you can rename the old one to keep a backup if you want)

**Tell firefox to use the new file instead of the cached one**

Now you need to tell firefox not to use the cached version of omni.js by adding this system env var:

MOZ_PURGE_CACHES
With the value of 1

To do this: click start, then start typing “edit environment…” and choose that.

Click environment variables, then on the top choose “New”, in the first box put MOZ_PURGE_CACHES and in the second put 1

Do “OK” and “OK” again

Run Firefox to see that it works now (enter a search term and click enter it should find it and disappear from the box)

**Re-enable cached omni.ja loading**

Go back to the environment variables editing and delete the entry that you added

Comment: Thanks for figuring out the right place to patch. I submitted this as an extension to the “fix Firefox” script, to automate it: https://github.com/SebastianSimon/firefox-omni-tweaks/pull/15

Comment: This has been merged; you can select this as a preset in the [web app](https://sebastiansimon.github.io/firefox-omni-tweaks/#clearSearchBarOnSubmit) to get a customized script to automate this, or you can execute the default script as `./fixfx.sh -o clearSearchBarOnSubmit`.